# Illegal reflective access operation occurring in Kotlin while trying to run a hello world program

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-12

I am trying to run Kotlin using IntelliJ and I can't run anything without getting an illegal reflective access operation. not even a hello world program.

I've tried checking for updates to Kotlin

The code I run is below. the error happens with and without the package.

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

I get the error

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil$2 (file:/Users/will.rogers/Library/Application%20Support/IntelliJIdea2019.1/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar) to constructor com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl()
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil$2
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: Is there is a bug in the JetBrains issue tracker for this?

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30387